# Selling multiple creatures together

Tags: battle-camp

Inventories get flooded with new creatures and besides feeding them to your rares you can sell them for coins. But is there a way i can sell multiple creatures together? Currently i have to manually click a creature, go to manage, sell and accept. Selling 20 creatures this way takes a lot of clicks and a lot of time on a wonky connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tap "edit" and select multiple creatures to store or sell from the same screen where you can select single creatures.